# Give the user response of logic app status?

Tags: logic, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating this Logic App that runs when the user clicks the link from the HTTP request. The user has no idea if the logic app is running or has failed. Is there a way to give the user a response, like the status of the logic app. So first status will be: 'Running' and when the logic apps is done the status will be: 'Succeeded!'?

greets

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the link, they will get a http 200 ok message from the logic app automatically.

if you want to specify the response, you can use the Response Connector and mention the StatusCode and the Body as required.

Comment: At the start I have a HTTP Request and in the last step I have a Response. Between this time a new page opens when the user clicks the link and keeps loading until it's finished and show the response. Between that time I want to let the user know to stay on that page and wait for response,

Comment: @crazybob, why don't you instruct the user beforehand to wait for response? The instruction (or rather the 'Running' status) shouldn't come from the Logic App.